# Can't use escape+backspace to delete a word in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Running VS Code on WSL.

I have tried opening keybindings.json at [USER]/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/keybindings.json

... and adding the following:

```json
  {
    "key": "escape+backspace",
    "command": "deleteWordLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
  }
```

To no avail. This despite the fact that:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+backspace",
    "command": "deleteWordLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

Works as intended. Is there some other escape command that I need to remove/disable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you can not use `escape` as a modifier, you can still use escape+backspace to delete a word in Visual Studio Code

```
  {
    "key": "escape backspace",
    "command": "deleteWordLeft",
    "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
  }
```

Notice the space between `escape` and `backspace`, you need to type `escape` followed by `backspace`, not simutaneously.

Comment: This works! And to think, I was an edit distance of one away from what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: But this will effectively disable Escape-bound actions like cancelling selection ranges or dismissing intelisense suggestions, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

According [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_accepted-keys), for **Modifier keys** only `Ctrl+`, `Shift+`, `Alt+` and `Meta/Win/Cmd+` are accepted, so it seems that `escape+` is not considered valid.

Comment: Thanks. In other words, it is not possible to do what I want here?

Comment: Yes, I guess it is not in VSC. Generally speaking, making any "normal" key act like a modifier key in combination with other keys is super interesting idea, but from what I've tried it might not be trivial / predictable / or sometimes even technically possible to achieve due hardware/firmware limitations.